# Location services are not functional in iOS 4.3 simulator running on Mac OS 10.7 with Xcode 4.2

Tags: macos, xcode4, core-location, osx-lion

I have built an iOS app that leverages Core Location Framework. I have Xcode 4.2 installed and Lion and now Location services are not functional.

Anyone know if there is a patch or workaround for this? I basically stuck and can't test my app on the simulator.

Comment: I am also having this problem, but with Xcode 4.1. Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: Can you test on the device as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated location services in the iOS Simulator are not available to the general public as of yet. If you have access to the iOS Developer Program, you can download the latest beta of XCode, 4.2, and test that way.

As a warning, the beta is just that, a beta. You may end up with more testing issues that are completely unrelated to your location services.

Best case scenario is 2 machines, one for each. That isn't always feasible, so you'll have to decide which is more important. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on the device would definitely be a good work around.  You will want to test on a real device to check Xcode 4.2 is still in Beta, so this might be a bug in this latest version.  According to the documentation it is supposed give you the latitude and longitude of the Apple headquarters as a default.

[iOS Simulator notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html)